# Erro ao efetuar requisição via POST

Tags: post, ionic2

Estou enviando informações para uma página no meu servidor via `GET` através do meu aplicativo, até ai esta funcionando normalmente. Porém, agora preciso enviar uma imagem no formato `base64`, creio que fazendo o envio via `POST` dê certo, mas quando tento enviar recebo o erro:

> Response with status: 0 for URL: null

Já tentei inclusive retirar a imagem dos parâmetros, mas recebo a mesma mensagem.

Na minha configuração adicionei o `proxy`:

```
"proxies": [{
  "path": "/api",
  "proxyUrl": "https://meu_site.com.br/MeuProjeto/api/"
}]
```

> OBS: O link no aplicativo esta correto, só ocultei aqui por questões de privacidade.

No meu `provider` está a chamada dos métodos `get` e `post`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ServiceProvider {

  urlApi: string = https://meu_site.com.br/MeuProjeto/api/';

  constructor(public http: Http) {

  }

    get(file: string){
      console.log("Requisição: " + this.urlApi + file);
      return this.http.get(this.urlApi + file).map(res => res.json());
    }

    post(file: string, params){
      let headers = new Headers( {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT',
        'Content-Type': 'Application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      });
      return this.http.post("/api" + file, params, {
        headers: headers
      }).map(res => res.json());
    }    
}
```

Chamo o método post da seguinte forma:

```
this.service.post('minha_pagina.php', params).subscribe(
  data =>{
  },
  err => {
  }
);
```

E ai recebo o erro que mencionei no inicio da pergunta. Já tentei de várias formas corrigir problemas com `CORS`, mas sem sucesso, abaixo vou colocar minha página que esta recebendo essa requisição:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
    header('Content-Type: Application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    //Conteúdo da página.
?>
```

Comment: Você realmente precisa enviar essa imagem no formato base64?

Answer (score 2):

Não existe status HTTP 0. Esse 0 significa o retorno da sua requisição. A segunda parte da mensagem de erro diz quanto a **URL: NULL**.
Uma coisa que notei, foi o seguinte trecho logo abaixo de exportar a classe ServiceProvider:

```
 urlApi: string = https://meu_site.com.br/MeuProjeto/api/';
```

Em que não há o primeiro ' antes do HTTP. Não sei se você já arrumou isso, mas ajustando, ficaria assim:

```
 urlApi: string = 'https://meu_site.com.br/MeuProjeto/api/';
```

Outra coisa que pode ser é o seu proxy:

```
"proxies": [{
  "path": "/api",
  "proxyUrl": "https://meu_site.com.br/MeuProjeto/api/"
}]
```

Será que ele não está concatenando o proxyUrl com o Path? Gerando a seguinte 
URL:

https://meu_site.com.br/MeuProjeto/api/**/api**

**(sendo esse final '/api' do path).**